# iOS Custom keyboard can't return focus to app's textfield

Tags: ios, uikit, uikeyboard, uiinputviewcontroller

I'm working on a custom keyboard for iOS which will have its own search field (similarly implemented by PopKey).

My keyboard's textfield is able to take the focus with `becomeFirstResponder` and I'm able to give it up by using `resignFirstResponder`. However after I resign focus, the host app has a difficult time retaking focus despite touching the form. The app's textfield will still show the text cursor blinking.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is a hack, as of right now you can't really give the host app its focus back.

- Subclass a `UITextField` and on its delegate implement
  `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` by returning `NO`.
- Add a `BOOL` property `isSelected` that gets set to `YES` in `touchesBegan` (not to be confused with the default `selected` property)
- In your keyboard's `keyPressed` method, if `searchField.isSelected`, manipulate the `searchField.text`. Else, manipulate `textDocumentProxy` like normal.
- Add a `clear` button and method that wipes `searchField.text` and `searchField.isSelected`, allowing any further keystrokes to return to the `textDocumentProxy`
- Add an animation that replicates the blinking type cursor